# How do I insert names into birthday invitations automatically?

Tags: lists

I am trying to create a LaTex document that will allow me to write the text of the birthday invitations once with the formatting I desire, and then have Latex automatically fill in the recipient's names from a list on each different one (as well as have multiple invitations per letter sized sheet of paper).

I have searched this sight as well as the [Latex wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX) and a Latex website for [templates](http://www.latextemplates.com/) (to see if anyone has done something similar) or similar concepts. I haven't found anything that would help me do this.

Comment: A solution does not have to rely on lists. For example, creating a macro `\invite{<name>}` would permit to create the desired invitations by using one `\invite` call per guest without an explicit list.

Comment: This question is related to [N ary switchs (selectors / conditionnals / toggles) to handle mailling list](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/232065/34551).

Answer (score 17):

I would suggest using a two-step approach:

1. Create a standard document layout that has the outline for the invitation set according to your requirements.
2. Use [`pdftk`](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) or [`pdfpages`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) (or something similar) to print the output in 2-up, 4-up, or whatever.

Regarding 1, here's a template:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=4in,paperheight=5.5in,margin=.5in]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\pagestyle{empty}% No page headers/footers
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% No paragraph indent
\newcommand{\createinvite}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\do}[1]{%
    \clearpage
    Dear ##1,\par\medskip
    \lipsum[1]\bigskip
    See you there,\par\medskip
    \textit{Random Randolfsky}
  }%
  \docsvlist{#1}%
}
\begin{document}
\createinvite{Tom,Dick,Harry,Susan}
\end{document}
```

[`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) sets the document layout and size, while [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) provided some dummy text. [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) provides the list-processing capability via `\docsvlist{<list of names>}`. The main function is `\do` which processes each element of the comma separated list. I've renewed it to print some salutation, followed by the invitation, followed by the signature.

Since `\clearpage` only clears the page if it is non-empty, there is no concern issuing it at the start of `\do`.

Comment: oh, please use ragged right!  this is a party, not a solemn symposium.

Comment: I have tried your solution. Thank you for the suggestion. The example was very helpful. I had trouble getting lipsum to work, but since I didn't need that to test the automatic names I went ahead and replaced it with actual text. It does automatically put names into the invites from a comma seperated list like I was wanting. =) Thank you!

Comment: @MarieMikels: Exactly. [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) is merely used to populate a document with dummy text and is not needed for the "end product". Consider using @_barbarabeeton's suggestion of `\raggedright`, just for fun. Also, if this answer helped you most, consider accepting it as such. See [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/5764)

Comment: Instead of `\raggedright` you should use the `ragged2e` package and `\RaggedRight`. Standard `\raggedright` looks awful.

Answer (score 15):

Here is a solution using a csv data file with the names, then using the datatool package to create the invitations, finally using Werner's recommandation to use a pdf printer to get 4up.  I used PDF995 (which was on my laptop).

First create the csv file.  I just used notepad to create the file and then did a save as to marie-names.txt

I now have the following file in csv format

```
FirstName
Bob the Tomatoe
Larry the Cucumber
Big Bird
Waldo (if found)
```

Now I modified the instructions found at http://latex-my.blogspot.com/2012/01/mail-merge-batch-generating-documents.html to get the following MWE.  Note: old-border.jpg is from http://www.fromoldbooks.org/Aubrey-HistoryOfEngland-Vol2/pages/438-Border-of-twigs/  and picture1.png was converted using powerpoint from http://aknockoutphoto.wordpress.com.

```
% Use scrartcl to allow larger base font size
\documentclass[16pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=6cm,bottom=5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wallpaper} % For background image frame

\usepackage{datatool}
% Load database 'names' from file 'marie-names.txt''
\DTLloaddb{firstnames}{marie-names.txt}%Import the txt file in csv format as a database
\begin{document}
\linespread{2}\selectfont %Changing linespacing for the font and enabling the change
\pagestyle{empty}% Turn of page numbers
% Set old-border.jpg as background image
\TileWallPaper{\paperwidth}{\paperheight}{old-border}%Loading a borderpattern
% Ref: http://www.fromoldbooks.org/Aubrey-HistoryOfEngland-Vol2/pages/438-Border-of-twigs/

% For each record (line) in database 'names'
% Assign field values by name to macros
\DTLforeach{firstnames}{\name=FirstName}{
  {\centering
    {\LARGE\bfseries Birthday Party Invitation}\par
   \smallskip\large Dear \name,\par\smallskip
   You are invited to a cookout to celebrate Cookie Monster's 44th birthday!\par
    \medskip
    Saturday, November 10, 2012 from 5:30 -- 9:00 p.m.\par 
    \medskip
    1234 Sesame Street\par 
    Anywhere, USA\par 
    \medskip
  Please RSVP to Miss Piggy at 987-654-abcd\par \bigskip
 \includegraphics{picture1.png}\par
    \pagebreak}
  }

\end{document}
```

Now compile with pdflatex and view.  Now print with a package capable of creating a 4up pdf page and your get

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Create a txt file consisting of rows of the following form:

```
\ADR{Paul}{Dirac}{m}{Highstreet}{7}{Edinburgh}
```

You can use up to 9 fields (because commands can't have more parameters in LaTeX). All entries must have the same number of fields.
Save this file e.g. as `adr.txt`
Then write your letter with latex and use:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\ADR}[6]{%
   \begin{letter}{#1 #2 \\#4\\#5}
   \opening{Dear #1,} 
   We would like to invite you ...
   \closing{Regards}
   \end{letter}
   }
\input{adr.txt}
\end{document}
```

All you have to do is to replace names, given names, street etc. with the field number of your `\ADR` definition. This should work on all letter classes.

Comment: I just edited the code to make a MWE.  Very nice idea.

Comment: @R.Schumacher I use the way of may edited answer. Each `begin{letter}` starts a new page, though no `\clearpage` is needed.