# Creating form letter in LyX

Tags: lyx, forms

This really refers to the following posting:

[How do I insert names into birthday invitations automatically?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60894/how-do-i-insert-names-into-birthday-invitations-automatically)

I've tried to used the suggested LaTeX coding in LyX and don't quite seem to get it to work.

Does anyone know if this is actually achievable in LyX or would I need to go back to native LaTeX code?

Here's an example - I would need to exchange the full name several times:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My approach (in LyX) is based on the LaTeX [package "datatool"](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/datatool).

For the **name list**, create a simple text file "studentlist.csv" with one name per line. The first line contains a heading!

```
Student Name
Peter M.
Tom J.
```

For the **LyX document**, add following to the "LaTeX Preamble":

```
\usepackage{datatool}
% load database 'studentlist' from file '/home/tux/studentlist.csv';
% in LyX the absolute path to the file is *necessary*!
\DTLloaddb{studentlist}{/home/tux/studentlist.csv}
```

Then write the main document starting with the following TeX code/ERT:

```
\DTLforeach{studentlist}
{\name=Student Name}
{
```

Write the main part of the document (Would a sans serif font look better?) and replace the names with TeX code/ERT `\name`. (The package "datatool" can do much more complex stuff, e.g., adding more fields or creating conditional texts - see [this example](http://latex-my.blogspot.com/2012/01/mail-merge-batch-generating-documents.html) or [datatool user documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/datatool/datatool-user.pdf).)
Probably you would also like to set "Page Layout > Headings style: empty".

Finally, insert a "Clear Page" and put as TeX code/ERT `}`. This will looks like:

[image: picture of lyx document]

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you very much! I was nearby there, but my CSV file didn't have a header and I also missed out the "clear page"!

Answer (score 1):

What I did when faced with something similar (mail the requests for a program committee to review papers) was to write a skeleton file using markers for the data to be replaced (reviever name, email, papers to review, ...) and use a Perl script to take the values from a simple file (fields separated by ';', essentially) to write a specific message for each member.

With LaTeX I'd probably create a skeleton that `\include`s a file defining macros, and switch those around.

Comment: The Perl solution sounds interesting. Does this mean that you end up with multiple files that you then need to compile separately?

Comment: @JoanneDemmler, that was what I did, yes. Or more precisely, I wrote a script that created a message to email from the template and the line with values on the fly and sent it out. Here I'd use the template to create a `.tex`, `pdflatex` it to PDF, rename/move to the final destination and go for the next entry in the control file. Here it is simpler, perhaps create files for each recipient, which `\include`s the template after defining commands for name and such?

Comment: I've played around with the macro and `\include` version for a while, but LyX bombarded me with unhelpful error messages (something about too may #'s). Another time...

Comment: @JoanneDemmler, dump LyX. Use a honest text editor and command line, as Knuth intendeth.

Comment: I probably just got something wrong in the preamble. I don't mind plain LaTeX for shortish documents, but I get badly lost in my code in very long documents.