# Showcase of beautiful invitations in TeX

Tags: typography, examples, big-list

I'm interested in using TeX and friends to produce beautifully typeset invitations (for parties, weddings, and especially thesis defences).  I understand that there is a package [`gcard`](http://ctan.org/pkg/gcard) for making folded greeting cards, but it's fairly simple.  I would love to see a list of, or links to, more sophisticated-looking examples for inspiration and motivation.  (If the complete source code is freely available and adaptable, so much the better.)

Comment: You might have a look at this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219774/showcase-of-programming-your-document-paradigm/219776#219776

Comment: Here is a discussion of using mailmerge to assist in content creation for invitations.  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60894/how-do-i-insert-names-into-birthday-invitations-automatically

Comment: And here is another one: [N ary switchs (selectors / conditionnals / toggles) to handle mailling list](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232065/n-ary-switchs-selectors-conditionnals-toggles-to-handle-mailling-list).

Comment: This one has always worked for me in any font: "Free beer!"

Answer (score 40):

I made an invitation using Xe/LuaLaTeX and a TikZ fading over an OpenStreetMap generated map excerpt.  Here is a [link](http://document.li/GRvM) to the map I used (I don't know how long it is valid).

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{geometry,fontspec,tikz}
\geometry{a6paper,landscape,hmargin={1cm,1cm},vmargin={1cm,1cm}}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Adobe Garamond Pro}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\tikzfading[name=fade right,
left color=transparent!0,
right color=transparent!100]
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \node[anchor=east,inner sep=0pt] (pic) at (current page.east)
    {\includegraphics[height=\pdfpageheight]{map}};
  \fill[white,path fading=fade right] (pic.north west) rectangle (pic.south east);
  \coordinate (pin) at (12,-2.5);
  \filldraw[ultra thick,draw=red,fill=red!50] (pin) -- ++(70:.5) arc (-20:200:.18) -- cycle;
  \path (pin) -- ++(0,.5) node[draw,fill,red,circle,inner sep=1pt] {};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\obeylines%
{\addfontfeatures{Scale=3,LetterSpace=10} INVITATION}

\bigbreak
\textit{%
  Dear friend,

  I'd love to invite you to my party.

  Sincerly, your friend.
}

\vfill

{\addfontfeatures{Scale=1.4,LetterSpace=5}\scshape when?}
\textit{%
  December 24\/\rlap{,}\textsuperscript{th} 2015
  8\kern.5pt:\kern.5pt30 pm
}
\medbreak
{\addfontfeatures{Scale=1.4,LetterSpace=5}\scshape where?}
\textit{%
  Times Square,
  London E1,
  UK
}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Very nice, simple, and lovely. How would you do it in a Lua version ?

Comment: @Julien I edited the file to also work with LuaLaTeX, i.e. I replaced `\XeTeXpdffile` with `\includegraphics`.  Also I set `inner sep=0pt` for the picture to get rid of the ugly white stripe on the right.

Comment: In my latex its telling that, fontsec package needs xelatex.. but how can I use this in my latex ??@HenriMenke

Comment: @David As noted in this showcase, you have to typeset this using either `xelatex` or `lualatex`.  Furthermore you need to have the “Adobe Garamond Pro” font installed.

Comment: I've just ran a test, awesome, this work perfectly. To be noted, I had to remove the font line specification (`\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Adobe Garamond Pro}`), since I don't have it on my laptop, still, it's looking very nice. Thanks.

Answer (score 25):

Thanks to everyone who's posted a sample invitation here.  For my own purposes, I decided in the end to go with something a bit different.  I'm posting it here in case anyone else would like to adapt it for themselves.

The invitation is printed on textured, A4-size card stock, folded in half to make A5 pages.  The inner page of the invitation uses a
decorative border from [the frontispiece of *Quadrans
Astrolabicus,*](http://www.fromoldbooks.org/Butsch-RenaissanceOrnament-VolII/pages/006-celtic-knotwork-border/)
a 1534 book written by [Oronce
Finé](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oronce_Fin%C3%A9) and printed in
Paris by [Simon de
Colines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_de_Colines).  The text is set in EB Garamond with occasional use of fancy ligatures and coloured initials.  Here's what it looks like:

[image: A fancy-looking invitation to Tristan Miller's doctoral thesis defence]

I also used the `labels` package to produce personalized RSVP cards.

Here is [a PDF demonstrating the inner page, outer page, and RSVP cards](https://github.com/logological/thesis-invitation/raw/master/sample_output.pdf).

The complete and freely licensed XeLaTeX source code is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/logological/thesis-invitation).

Comment: Fantastic! Only for this you deserve the Ph. D. :-)

Comment: This is beautiful and sadly too nice to just pick up and reuse... Great work nevertheless.

Comment: A bit off-topic, but your thesis is actually very interesting!! I'm a huge fan of puns btw :)

Answer (score 17):

This is not an invitation, but Paulo sent me this really nice christmas card.  Thank you, Paulo!

> [image]

Comment: Yours didn't get rained on ;).

Answer (score 14):

I wrote one up in my article on using Zapfino in Omega: http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb24-2/tb77adams.pdf

[image: multi-lingual Peace on Earth]

Answer (score 14):

This is more like a poster, but would work for a flyer as well:
[image: Jazz at the Institute]

Here are links to the [source file](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/%7Eantoine.chambert-loir/publications/jati/jati.tex) and to the [pdf version](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/%7Eantoine.chambert-loir/publications/jati/jati.pdf).

Comment: The source file is not available anymore :-(

Comment: I corrected the links, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9):

I made an invitation recently. This thread was very helpful, along with:

- [The LaTeX Font Catalog](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/)
- the [pgfornament](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfornament) package

[image]

Source: https://gitlab.com/bengreenman/wedding-invitation

Answer (score 6):

Not an invitation, but a Christmas card.

Most relevant packages for the graphics:

- [EBGaramond](https://ctan.org/pkg/ebgaramond) (font)
- [PGFOrnament](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfornament)

Includes source code on back, typeset with [listings](https://ctan.org/pkg/listings). Folding marks made manually with [TikZ](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf).

Print on A4 paper, cut off bottom bar, fold in the middle and it perfectly fits inside a DL envelope.

[image: card]

Source: https://github.com/Kamik423/christmas-card-2019

I created [an updated version vor 2021](https://github.com/Kamik423/christmas-card-2021), this time using the Antykwa Półtawskiego font. Especially this last one was very much inspired by [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/294018/123949).

[image: card]

[image: card]